# In Wordpress, post_parent returns 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I just started customizing my own Wordpress website. I have some experience in PHP programming, but I can't get this one to work.

With the wp-types plugin I created a parent-children relationship. When I request the ID of the parent, it always returns zero:

```
echo "Parent PostID: " . $post->post_parent . "<br>";
```

This is the same for the wp_get_post_parent_id function.

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `post_parent` is a WordPress core feature, and isn't related to the parent-child relationships set up in the Types plugin. (The relationship in Types is stored in custom fields on the posts.)

A [post on the Types support forum suggests](http://wp-types.com/forums/topic/it-would-be-nice-to-have-types_parent_post-as-well-as-types_child_posts/) suggests this method for finding the parent of a post in Types:

```
$parent_id = wpcf_pr_post_get_belongs(get_the_ID(), 'parent-type-slug');
if (!empty($parent_id)) {
  $parent = get_post($parent_id);
}
```

(It's slightly easier to go the other way around, as there's a [`types_child_posts`](http://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/querying-and-displaying-child-posts/) method for returning the Types children of a post.)

Comment: Thank you very much, Matt. This should do the trick. I just googled the wpcf_pr_post_get_belongs function, but it doesn't give me much information. I'm in this learning process, and it would be a shame to just copy the code. Where can I find more documentation on it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure you can—the developer documentation for Types doesn't seem to be that deep in places. Asking on their support forums is probably the best you're going to get if a search turns up nothing...